# Should I take any action over "Crawled - currently not indexed" or let it go?

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, google-index, pagination, coverage

[image]

More of these pages are appearing on the "crawled currently not indexed" section of the Google Search Console coverage report.  I believe this is somewhat related to pagination and I should block it.

What steps should I take to avoid this happening?

Comment: See also [What can cause “Discovered - currently not indexed” in the new GWT](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112227/what-can-cause-discovered-currently-not-indexed-in-the-new-gwt) and [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for Google not to index every page on a website.  Most sites with more than a couple dozen pages have some pages that don't get indexed.  That is perfectly normal.   Google often chooses not to index a page for a variety of reasons:

- The content is duplicate (found elsewhere)
- The content is thin or too short
- The content doesn't look well written or compelling
- Users haven't reacted well to the content
- The content doesn't have enough inbound links to make it look important

Your paginated pages are some combination of those.  It looks like those contain the pagination of all the posts to your site.   Those pages don't have a lot of search engine value.  Those pages only show content summaries of several posts.   The full content of each post can be found on its own page.   The only link to each page may be from the previous page.

Even if Google chooses not to index your pages, they are not usually hurting the rest of your site.  The only time that they would hurt would be if there were so many of them that Googlebot were having a hard time crawling all of them to find the content that actually matters.

Allowing these pages to be crawled and indexed could be the only way on your site to allow Googlebot to find your post pages.  If that is true, preventing these pages from being indexed could hurt the other pages on your site.

Comment: I've been facing the same problem for quite some time now. But if I inspect the URL, GSC tells me that the URL is already on Google. 

If I request a re-indexing, however, then the problem is solved for that particular page after a couple of days.